# Memory leak from bitmap

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, bitmap

just tested my app and I've noticed after playing a while on the phone with MAT that I have a memory leak. My first thought was that the background image seted to the relative layout would be  the problem and after I've deleted the `android:background="@drawable/abc"` line in the xml file the memory leak problem disappeared.

I know I have to call recycle on the bitmaps that I used but before doing that I have some questions:

1. Is it ok to set the background images of the layouts inside the layout code as this :

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/abc"?
   >
   ```
2. Or just set an ImageView to the XML and then set it as a background drawable?

Comment: You refer to load a scaled down version into Memory?

Comment: yes follow the docs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory is occupied when activity is `created`. But if you manage to release them while activity is `destroyed`, almost memory leak problem will resolve.

Write following code in your `onDestroy()` method.

```
relativeLayout.setBackroundResource(null);
```

This will remove the background of your relative layout.

**Edit**

```
relativeLayout.setBackground(0);
```

> Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a Drawable object or 0 to remove the background.

Reference : [setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)

Comment: Just tested and it works. Can i use this line in OnPause() method if I will not reused that activity?

Comment: Yes, you can use that. But this will show u a black background before activity is destroyed. Best way is to use in `onDestroy()`. Coz destroy will called after activity is destroyed. So no one will see that you have removed background.

Comment: Thank's a lot for all the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

It has no meaning.. You can do it either way..
You can get later the refernece to the bitmap(src) and use recycle

Comment: Even if the image background is set in the relativelayout?

Comment: Thank's a lot for helping.